# How do we control web page caching for resources on OSGI?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, osgi-bundle, sling

I need to cache resources(images and fonts) which are coming from AEM.Using SlingHttpServletRequest i can grab all the resources paths.so how can i put actual resource into browser cache.i checked it using slingResponse.setHeader().but still was unable to find a method to putting resource path and making them into browser cache.

Comment: Besides the caching provided by the Dispatcher?

Comment: Dispatcher caching was implemented already.need to implement a browser cache.

Comment: Ok, yes, in that case, you can add those headers to let the browser knows that it can store files on cache. You can use extensions or regex to match certain patterns or locations.

Answer (score 2):

Browser cache is controlled using [Cache-Control](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http-cache-headers) headers. This ideally needs to be set up on the dispatcher. On a standard set up dispatcher isn't configured to cache response headers. So any headers set on the server will not be used for subsequent requests when it is served from cache.

Use the [mod_headers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) module on the dispatcher to send out max-age or expires values for the files you are interested in.

Ex: To cache all static resources for 1 year on the browser use

```
<LocationMatch "^\/etc\/designs\/my-project\/clientlibs-site\/(css|images|fonts|placeholders)\/.*">
  Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000"
</LocationMatch>
```

On encountering the cache control headers browsers will cache the resources.

Comment: why u are telling it is better to set up this in dispatcher rather aem itself ?

Comment: Content is served from dispatcher most of the time and response headers sent by AEM aren’t saved by default

Comment: In AEM i set response header like respose.setHeader("Cache-control", "private max-age=31536000"); is that fine ? when i check related resource it is showing the set values.

Comment: Do you have a dispatcher on the environment and does it show the header from repeat requests on the dispatcher

Comment: Is that the only way to check this is working fine.other than that how can i check it is working fine?